# How do I make a menu that a user can choose from

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a menu where a user can choose from a list of options. After they choose one of the options it will display a `cout<<` after that is done, i want it to loop back to the menu so they can choose another option.. here is my code so far. It is not finished but i tried everything from making that section part of a variable.. like giving it a value of 1 and when it goes to an option i change that variable so it doesn't loop but after its done i put it back to 1.. but that isn't working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int option=0;
    int main = 0;

    cout << "Hello there...\n\nToday we are going to do a little fun project that I created.\n\n";
    cin.get();

    cout << "\nAs we progress throughout this program, I will explain the different things\n";
    cout << "that we are going to do. We will be covering some basic C++ excersises.";
    cout << "\n\nFirst and foremost we will  begin by  covering what I have learned so far....\n\n";
    cin.get();

    cout << "The first topic we will cover will include what is known as 'variables'.\n";
    cout << "what are variables you ask?";
    cin.get();

    while (10)
    {
        cout << "\n\n\nEnter the number of one of the following and I will explain!\n";
        cout << "1.integer  2.boolian   3.floats   4.doubles   5.character";
        cout << "\n\n[when you are done type 'done' to continue]\n\n";
        cin >> option;
    }

    if (option = 1);
    {
        cout << "\nInteger is the variable abbreviated as 'int' this allows C++ to only";
        cout<<"\nreadwhole and real numbers \n\n";
    }



}
```

Comment: _'but that isn't working'_ Is a bit vague?!? ...

Comment: `while (10)`? No. Also, `option` cannot be `"done"` because it is an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to have all the menu logic in that `while` loop you set up.  The current `while (10)` condition you have should result in an infinite loop; that is likely why your current version is not working.  I would try modifying your `while` loop like this:

```
while (option != -1) // put whatever your loop exit condition is here
{
    cout << "\n\n\nEnter the number of one of the following and I will explain!\n";
    cout << "1.integer  2.boolian   3.floats   4.doubles   5.character";
    cout << "\n\n[when you are done type 'done' to continue]\n\n";
    cin >> option;

    if (option == 1)
    {
        cout << "\nInteger is the variable abbreviated as 'int' this allows C++ to only";
        cout<<"\nreadwhole and real numbers \n\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the input in a string if you want to support `"done"` then convert it to `int` with [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). Use `switch` instead of a bunch of `if`s and `while(true)` to keep on going until the `break` keyword is used.

```
std::string in;
int op = 0;

while (true)
{
  // PRINT OPTIONS
  // GET INPUT

  if (in == "done") break;

  switch (std::stoi(in))
  {
    case 1:
      // OPTION 1
    break;
    case 2:
      // OPTION 2
    break;
    default:
      // INVALID OPTION
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa a `do while` control flow block and check for a particular input that makes the program end.

for example you can change the main structure of your program like this:

```
int flag = 1;
char c = 'a';
do {
    cout << "SHOW THE MENU " << endl;
    cout << "press 'x' to exit" << endl;
    cin>>c;

    if(c == '1')
    {
        cout << "doing 1" << endl;
    } 
    else if (c == '2') 
    {
        cout << "doing 2" << endl;
    }
}  while(c != 'x');
```

Comment: that is obvious, I wanted him/her to show a little effort in understanding the problem.

Comment: I don't think so, the overall quality of the code in the question says it all on the effort spent in searching for a solution.. 
look at this for example... `if (option = 1);`